# Angular2 - Error while mapping data from WebAPI (Error: Error trying to diff )

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying various to fetch data from API and to show it in a list using `ngFor`. I have tried promises, observable and played around with map, subscribe, async pipe but no luck yet. I am certain the API has been hit but for some reason, it either shows blank data or throws different errors. The most recent I've got is

> Error trying to diff '[{"id":1,"name":"Bike 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Bike
>   2"},{"id":3,"name":"Bike 3"}]'
>       at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff..

I have a hunch that the function isn't returning an array which is expected by ngFor.

Following is my **add-bike.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bike } from "./Entity/bike";
import { BikeService } from "./bike.service";
@Component({
    selector: 'add-bike',
    template : `<p>Hello</p><ul>
            <li *ngFor="let bike of bikes">
                {{ bike.name}}
            </li>            
        </ul>`
})

export class AddBikeComponent implements OnInit {

    bikes: Bike[] = [];
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private bikeService: BikeService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.bikeService.getRequest().subscribe(res => this.bikes = res);
    }
}
```

**bike.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Bike } from './Entity/bike';

@Injectable()
export class BikeService {
    private _url = 'api/bikes'; 
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getRequest() {
        return this.http.get(this._url).map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

**bike.ts**

```
export class Bike {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

**Web API code in C#:**

```
public class Bike
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            List<Bike> list = new List<Bike>();
            list.Add(new Bike() { id = 1, name = "Bike 1" });
            list.Add(new Bike() { id = 2, name = "Bike 2" });
            list.Add(new Bike() { id = 3, name = "Bike 3" });
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list));
        }
```

Api response: api/bikes

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Bike 1\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Bike 2\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Bike 3\"}]"
```

Comment: Can you post the typescript definition of `Bike` ?

Comment: Can you try displaying `bikes` instead of `*ngFor`ing it? just `{{bikes}}` and let us know what's displayed. Maybe try `{{bikes|json}}` too

Comment: Did you try by using by using `interface` instead of `class`. Usually, we use `interfaces` for "model objects".

Comment: @Amit {{bikes}} shows up nothing.

Comment: Do you still get the error when removing the `*ngFor`?

Comment: It worked after adding json.parse(). @Amit

Comment: @Sangram could you try  my answer and let me know is it a proper one for your scenario or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If WebApi returns a class type, you don't have to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

I didn't try this together with the rest of your code, but probably changing your return method to this might work;

```
return Ok(list);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I somehow overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting from your response is in format that you currently need to parse to JSON, you can do it by adding a second map:

```
getRequest() {
    return this.http.get(this._url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => JSON.parse(res))
}
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/onfdvVmoCO3DVqgXn9cz?p=preview

Comment: Thank's a lot. I had a hunch that I'd need to parse it. But I was not able to figure out where to put json.parse(). Also, Could you add what changes I need to do to avoid json parsing,

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# unfortunately, but try what @coni2k suggested. The underlying problem is how you are sending the data from the backend. You need to send it as JSON string without the slashes like `[{"someprop":"propValue", ....}]`, then you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

bike.service.ts

```
getRequest() {
        return this.http.get(this._url).map(res => res.json() as  Bike[]);
    }
```

Make sure of Bike Entity

```
export class Bike {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```